# Why contents of a div are not shown while dragging with the draggable="true"?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, draggable

So I'm using the `draggable="true"` for a div that holds couple of other divs with `span` classes applied from [Twitter's Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/). The problem that raises is when I'm dragging the holder the children elements are not shown. If I remove the classes from Bootstrap then the elements are shown during drag.

The broken example can be found on [jsfiddle.net/8umGq/](http://jsfiddle.net/8umGq/4/).

What exactly is causing the problem and what should I probably override in order to use the `span` classes and still see the contents while dragging?

I want to make it work on a latest or beta release of Chrome and still preserve style and the positions of the `span` classes.

Comment: Interesting. That's a strange behavior. Does that occur in various browsers?

Comment: @fdomig tested on Chrome and I don't care about other browsers at the moment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to fix it by adding `position: relative;` to the `.holder` element.

See example here [jsfiddle.net/bq9qw/](http://jsfiddle.net/bq9qw/)

Comment: I don't know if you noticed but this changes dramatically the sizes of the span elements. The whole idea of having these exactly spans will make no sense... http://i.imgur.com/6bVAX.png

Comment: Yes, you are right. I managed to fix it by adding position: relative; to the holder: http://jsfiddle.net/bq9qw/

Comment: Pretty cool.. update your answer to the latest form and I'll try it on my project to see if it works as expected there as well.

Comment: You can delete the broken example and remove the edit word since it can be accessed through the history for reference if needed: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/12827915/revisions

Answer (score -2):

I think you have to fall back to jQuery to get the draggable functionality to work correctly, as such:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .holder {
            height: 20px;
            background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
        }

        .span2 {
            background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5);
        }
    </style>
    <link href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function init(){
            $('div.holder').draggable();
        }

        $(document).ready(function(){init()});
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
    <div class="holder">
        <div class="span2">
            Foo
        </div>
        <div class="span2">
            Bar
        </div>
    </div>
</div>​
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The whole point was not to use anything external.. If wanted to include the overhead of the jQuery UI I would bother trying the HTML5 approach.